# Android - listView's click gives index out of bounds exception

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a `ListView` where i am storing some URLs and i load the contents of the listview using an arraylist which is of the type `ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>`. I am trying to handle the click of this list using the following code snippet.

```
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int pos,
                long arg3) {
            System.out.println("List Clicked..." + pos);
            System.out.println("URL: " + listView.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString());
        }
    });
```

The first SOP is executed correctly, but the second print statement is giving me the following error
`ERROR/AndroidRuntime(382): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid location 0, size is 0`

Here is my adapter's `getView()`

```
        @Override
    public View getView(int position, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        View v = arg1;

        if (v == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);    

        } 
        t1=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        HashMap<String, String> values = storedURLArrayList.get(position);
        t1.setText(values.get("value"));
        return v;
    }
```

Please help.

Comment: are you using custom Adapter or custom ListView...?

Comment: I think listView.getItemAtPosition(pos) will give you a particular HashMap lying at the clicked position so here may be a problem. I am not sure but..

Comment: can you please add some more code & explanation about your problem?

Comment: I am getting a listview from xml and m using a custom adapter to load it.

Comment: @PM, Paresh: i dont think that is the problem, because `HashMap<String, String> temp1 = (HashMap<String, String>) listView.getItemAtPosition(pos);` is again giving me the same error.

Comment: I have added more info about the adapter, check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a fix, though **i would like to know where the problem was**.

I was getting the position of list item. So, i decided to directly fetch value from `ArrayList`, and iterated through the `HashMap` to get the URL stored on that particular position.

```
HashMap<String, String> temp = URLArrayList.get(pos);
            Iterator<String> myIterator = temp.keySet().iterator();
            int count = temp.size()-1;
            String value = null;
            while(myIterator.hasNext()) {
                String key=(String)myIterator.next();
                value=(String)temp.get(key);
            }
```

Thanks everyone for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

@Shafi can't give answer in such short code, but many assumptions possible here:

1. Based on your above comment that you are using custom adapter to load it, check your **`getCount()`** method, there may be return 0 statement, it is wrong , you need to return the size of either array or arraylist.

For example:

```
public int getCount() {
        return listData.size();  
       // listData is the arrayList that you want to bind to listview
    }
```

Comment: @Paresh I have added more info about the adapter, check it out. There is no problem with the count. I have overridden the `getCount()` method and i am able to view and update the list.

Answer (score 1):

There is not necessary to loop thru the list, use the object key to find the value is good enough. Please check code below.

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    HashMap<String, String> o = myList.get(position);
        Toast.makeText(YumyumActivity.this, "ID '" + o.get("category_id") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

    }
});
```